# Running depending sbt tasks

Tags: scala, sbt

I have simple tasks task1 and task2 in .sbt file and then I made task2 depend on task1 by reassigning the task2 two different times:

```
val task1 = taskKey[String]("task1 original")
val task2 = taskKey[String]("task2 original")

task1 := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  log.error("task1 original output")
  "task1 original output"
}
task2 := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  log.error("task2 original output")
  "task2 original output"
}

task2 := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  log.error("task2 chain1 before task1.value")
  val x = task1.value
  log.error("task2 chain1 before task2.value")
  task2.value
}

task2 := {
  val log = streams.value.log
  log.error("task2 chain2 before task1.value")
  val x = task1.value
  log.error("task2 chain2 before task2.value")
  val y = task2.value
  log.error("task2 chain2 before task2.value")
  task2.value
}
```

When I load the sbt and run them I get following output:

```
> task1
[error] task1 original output
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 26, 2017 1:50:53 PM
> task2
[error] task1 original output
[error] task2 original output
[error] task2 chain1 before task1.value
[error] task2 chain1 before task2.value
[error] task2 chain2 before task1.value
[error] task2 chain2 before task2.value
[error] task2 chain2 before task2.value
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Mar 26, 2017 1:50:56 PM
```

Why is this working as it seems? Why is task2 calling older task2 assignements and not causing infinite loop?

What is the exact order in which the tasks are run? The logging output might not correspond the actual order in which the tasks are run. Is there a reliable way to record the order in which tasks have run?

Thank you for your support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a task, sbt calculates a [graph of task dependencies](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Task-Graph.html). Within this graph, each task is computed only once without recursion. It is however possible for a setting or task to depend on a previous value of the setting or task, which are also only computed once.

The order of tasks is not specified, except that tasks that depend on others will run after their dependencies. Independent tasks may also run in parallel. If you need a strict ordering, you need to make them depend on another.

For example:

```
task2 := task2.dependsOn(task1)
```